# Why code::blocks shows problem during compilation of C++ file

Tags: c++

I installed code::blocks before but I have never encountered a problem during the execution of a hello world program, which everyone must be familiar of. Today, I installed code::blocks along with GNU compiler and added it to PATH (environment variable). Everything seems right, but when I run the below code, it showed an error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(I build and run the code and the messages are as follows)

```
Project/Target: "FileTest - Debug":
  The compiler's setup (GNU GCC Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
  Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
  Do you have a compiler installed?
Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.

Tried to run compiler executable 'C:\MinGW/bin/gcc.exe', but failed!

Skipping...
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

I don't quite know what this log meant. I installed MinGW and when I went to **Settings / Compiler**, it just showed that I am using MinGW. Everything seems right.

Here is a screenshot from my editor:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdKCT.png.
Anyone help me?

Comment: Are you by chance running code-blocks 20.03 on a 32-bit version of windows? Have you considered making the path-separators consistent in `'C:\MinGW/bin/gcc.exe'`?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you can try `C:\MinGW/bin/g++.exe` for this ?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am using the 64-bit version of windows, so I installed the 64-bit version (There is also a GNU compiler in the folder.)

Comment: @OsmanDurdag I don't quite know your meaning. How should I set it in code::blocks?

Comment: check your compiler settings. It's been a long time since I used codeblocks, I don't remember exactly :)

Comment: Ok, you are not hit by the 32-bit bug in the MinGW distributed with version 20.03. Code::Blocks is usually pretty-good at picking up your MinGW install. Did code::blocks set the `'C:\MinGW/bin/gcc.exe'` or did you type it in? Also did you install a separate version of MinGW, or the one bundled with the Code::Blocks installer? What version of Code::Blocks?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What is path-seperator? (I am a C++ beginner, so are there resources for this? Grateful!)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I set it in Control Panel, and I typed it in there.

Comment: The `'\'` between the `C:...` and then `'/'` between the `MinGW` and `bin`. You are using two different forms. Use one or the other. Code::Blocks should accept `C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe` but it may not like seeing both `'\'` and `'/'` used in one path.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I know I used the bundle-up version of GNU.

Comment: I copied it from the top of the File Explorer, so I think it is correct.

Comment: Well -- you can't always rely on that. If you copied from windows explorer, it should be `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`, windows itself doesn't use the `'/'` as a separator.

Comment: OK. So what should I do?

Comment: Oops. I did not do gcc.exe. Is that a required operation?

Comment: Will it cause my program to fail or something?

Comment: You can look in the folder and see. There should be `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe`. Give me a sec and I"ll boot windows and check what paths are needed. You shouldn't hve to specify the exact C/C++ compiler. If I recall correctly, you just tell code::blocks the directly it is installed in like `C:\MinGW`. Hold on.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I changed the Path variable according to your instruction but it still displayed the same error. Is there something I missed?

Comment: I'm confused. I just started windows and ran code::blocks and you don't type a compiler in anywhere. You use either (if you are in a project) `Project -> Build Options...` and select a compiler from the drop-down list. Or to set the global default you use `Settings -> Compiler Settings...` and chose from the drop-down list as well. Where are you attempting to type the compiler location in??

Comment: You can set your windows environment path (top box in user settings) to contain `C:\MinGW\bin` if you want to be able to call gcc from the Command Prompt, but aside from that you shouldn't have to type in a MinGW path unless code::blocks simply cannot find a MinGW directory on your computer (which would be rare... and strange). Code::Blocks will do a compiler search each time it is started, so if you install Code::Blocks and then install a new compiler, simply restarting Code::Blocks should find the compiler and make it available via the drop-down lists.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I know that code::blocks does not allow users to enter the compiler. I also searched for it. I discovered that the version packed along with MinGW is the result, and I copied the path of it to PATH environment variable. According to videos on youtube, I expect this process of installation to succeed. However, after installation, it shows the bug.

Comment: Recall, after changing the user path variable, you will need to restart cmd.exe. I do it both ways. I have code::blocks bundled with MinGW and I have code::blocks where I installed a separate version of MinGW. Both work fine. You need to ensure you have the `/full/path/to/MinGW/bin` as the added path in the user environment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I did it. And it failed again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, It was a Environment error,

1. Download the mingw-setup.exe file from Code::Blocks ide.
2. Install
3. Go to Settings -> Compiler -> Reset Defaults

Answer (score 0):

It says the code::blocks can't find the compiler. So, naturally it will be invalid. Try uninstalling the code::blocks IDE & from the site of code::blocks install the minGW setup. I am giving this link, see it works or not.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/20.03/Windows/codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe/download

Comment: I downloaded the Code::Blocks IDE and I discovered it was the same file as the original installation. Thus, now my program can't even run. I checked the PATH variable, but everything is correct.